# Iptables appends rule default after "-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited"

Tags: iptables

I use iptables to open port 80 for HTTP on CentOS 6.4
I usually use vim to edit the /etc/sysconfig/iptables
But this time I use /sbin/iptables command.

```
# /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
# service iptables save
# service iptables restart
```

When I list the rules I can see http like this:

```
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh 
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:http
```

But I can not connect to web server from other machine
I checked the iptables file and I see the content like this:

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [88:9264]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
```

I had to manual put the line:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

before

```
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

and then when I restart iptables service. It worked!

So how can append new rules in a right way?
Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `-A` command to iptables simply "appends" a rule.  So if you're existing ruleset looks like this:

```
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh 
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

And you run:

```
# /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Then of course this will end up after the `REJECT` rule (because you told it to append the rule to the existing rulset).  You have a few choices:

1. You can simply edit `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` by hand, insert the rules you want, and run `service iptables restart`.
2. You can use the `lokkit` tool to modify the firewall instead. E.g., `lokkit -p 80:tcp`.  This will automatically update `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` as well as the active firewall.
3. You can use the `-I <num>` flag to `iptables` to insert the rule at the specified position in the list.  The `--line-numbers` flag can be useful for figuring out what `<num>` should be.  You'll need to run `service iptables save` after making changes this way.

If you really want to be able to do this sort of thing using just append commands, you'll need to perform a little setup first.  Create a new chain (called, maybe, `allow_services`):

```
iptables -N allow_services
```

And add a rule to your `INPUT` chain in the appropriate place that jumps to this new chain:

```
iptables -I INPUT 5 -j allow_services
```

And from that point on, you can simply append new services to the `allow_services` chain:

```
iptables -A allow_services -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Assuming that you place your jump rule (the `-j`  option) before the final `REJECT` this will do what you seem to be asking.

Comment: Woah so except specify the line number to append then there is no way to append the rule without manual check?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  The "append" flag (`-A`) simply appends a rule to the end of your ruleset.  If you need to place the rule somewhere *besides* the end of your ruleset, you're no longer appending, so you need a different solution.

Comment: Sorry because my explanation. Follow you guide I found that I have to specific line number to insert the rule like this: **/sbin/iptables -I INPUT 5 -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT** then it works. But there is no way to config using only iptables without specify the line number to insert?

Comment: I think that the options I had previously presented are all viable alternatives (I am particularly fond of just hand-editing `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`), but I've updated my answer with an alternative that will maybe get you where you want to be.

Comment: Or you can just re-run `system-config-firewall-tui`.

Comment: yeah I know. The reason is I want to write a script to automatically insert new rules to open those ports on dev server then I realize that iptables does not provide such a intelligent way to do it :D I'll use the -I option. Thank for you guys answers. Cheers!

Comment: For scripting, the `lokkit` command is probably your best choice.

Comment: It hasn't been mentioned explicitly yet, but if you use `-I` without a number, it does the opposite of `-A` and puts the rule at the very TOP of the chain, rather than the very bottom (effectively, the number defaults to `1` if you omit it)